# AngularJS directive to replace text with ng-click in it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a directive in Angular that takes a set of properties manipulates the some text and outputs it to the element.

The problem i'm having is I want to have some of the text wrapped in a ng-click which is to call a function from the scope that will in the end open a dialog box.

I have created a very simple example here which once working will let me expand on it: http://jsfiddle.net/BEuvE/

```
app.directive('parseString', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: { props: '=parseString' },
    link: function compile(scope, element, attrs) { 
      var nameHTML = '<a href="#" ng-click="helloPerson('+scope.props.name+')">'
          +scope.props.name+'</a>';
      var html = scope.props.text.replace('world', nameHTML);
      element.html(html);
    }
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at my fork of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/joakimbeng/aVjtv/1/
To make it work you need to use the $compile provider. My example isn't that clean, but I hope you get the point :)

Add the $compile dependency and compile your changed html:

```
app.directive('parseUrl', function($compile) {
    ...
    link: function compile(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
        angular.forEach(value.match(urlPattern), function(url) {
            value = value.replace(url, "<a target=\"" + scope.props.target + "\" ng-click='onClick()'>" + url +"</a>");
        });
        // The wrapping of the content in a div is required because
        // Angular wants only one element at root level
        var content = angular.element('<div></div>').html(value).contents();
        var compiled = $compile(content);
        element.html(''); // Clearing old text
        element.append(content); // Using append because "content" is DOMElements now, instead of a string
        scope.onClick= function () {
            console.log('clicked');
        };
        compiled(scope); // Linking compiled elements to scope
     ...
```