# How to change li to input filed when click on li?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
**HTML**

<ul class="ul_nav">
    <li ng-repeat="teams in teamArray" ng-class="{class : classVar==='{{ teams.team_id }}' }">
        <i ng-show="classVar === '{{ teams.team_id }}'" class="fa fa-pencil pen" ng-click="teamEdit(teams)"></i>
        <span ng-click="changeClass(teams.team_id)">{{ teams.team_name }}</span>
        <i ng-click="deleteTeam(teams.team_id)" ng-show="classVar === '{{ teams.team_id }}'" class="fa fa-times" title="Close"></i>
    </li>
    <input ng-keydown="$event.which === 13 && editTeam()" class="team_input" type="text" ng-show="args.team_name" ng-model="args.team_name">
</ul>

**JS**

$scope.myVar = false;
$scope.changeClass = function(value){
    $scope.classVar = value;
};
$scope.teamEdit = function(teams) {
    $scope.args = {
        team_name : teams.team_name,
        team_id : teams.team_id,
    };
};
```

When click on one li, I need to change it as a input field (type="text").How to do this using angularjs. [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ty1mExiVmHagMLfiWCgB?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer this is a directive which is replacing tags

[replace tag on ng-click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22640527/angularjs-directive-to-replace-tags-with-an-ngclick-function)

[fiddle for replacement](http://jsfiddle.net/hv7Pj/9/)

```
app.directive('parseTags', function ($compile) {
var pattern = /(^|\s)#([^\s]+)/g;
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
        ngModel: '=ngModel'
    },
    link: function compile(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
        scope.$watch('ngModel', function (value) {
            angular.forEach(value.match(pattern), function (tag) {
                var nohash = tag.replace(/#/g, '');
                console.log(nohash);
                value = value.replace(tag, "<a ng-click='onClick(\"" + nohash + "\")'>" + tag + "</a>");
            });

            var content = angular.element('<span></span>').html(value).contents();
            var compiled = $compile(content);
            element.html('');
            element.append(content);
            scope.onClick = function (tag) {
                alert(tag);
            };

            compiled(scope)
        });
    }
};
});
```

Other solutions would be to use disabled input and enable it or hide the li and show the input